# Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "String", Toast.LENGTH_LONG); ==>Here getApplicationContext() cannot change to "this"?

Tags: android, this, toast, android-context

First the format of Toast.makeText():

`public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int duration)`
the first argument is ***Context***, the function ***getApplicationContext()*** also return the current context, everything is ok, but IMO, the ***getApplicationContext()*** can also be replaced with this, just as follows:

```
public class ContextMenuResourcesActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private Button b1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final int l = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    final String s1 = "some string";
    b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(this, s1, l);
                t1.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

IMO `this` stands for the class `ContextMenuResourcesActivity`, which extends `Context`, so it can replace the first argument which demands for ***Context***, but I failed, can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a new `OnClickListener`, you are creating a anonymous class which implements a particular interface. Thus, `this` does not refer to the `Activity`, since you are actually in another object.

Here's some more info on the subject  [Anonymous classes vs delegates](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/166327/Anonymous-Classes-vs-Delegates)

Comment: Thanks, i didnt consider the anonymous class before.

Answer (score 0):

Iin this case this is indicating OnClickListener instance, to create view, or other UI stuff, you need to get context, this can be done by following different methods:

```
getApplicationContext();
ContextMenuResourcesActivity.this;
v.getContext();
```

Answer (score -1):

new OnClickListner() is an anonymous class that implements onclick interface and this refers to the instance of the anonymous class. Rather use "Your_Activity_Name.this"  to refer to the current context of your activity.